# How to get the Uploaded Files in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

Hi all i am uploading the files uploaded by the user in this path

```
       string savefilename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFiles/"),
                                Path.GetFileName());
```

And i am saving the Url in the Database in the Url Column in this

```
        ~/Content/UploadedFiles/BugTrackerDataBase.xlsx
```

and i am trying to retrieve the file Uploaded by the user by a link in my grid view
my retrieve method looks like this

```
       public ActionResult ViewAttachments(string AttachmentName)
           {
          try
           {
            AttachmentName = Session["AttachmentUrl"].ToString();
            var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("'" + AttachmentName + "'"));
            return File(fs, "application/doc", AttachmentName);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + AttachmentName);
        }
    }
```

and i have the Excepiton

```
      "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\AnilWork\BugTracker\BugTracker\ViewBug\'UploadedFiles\BugTrackerDataBase.xlsx''."
```

can any one tell me where am i doing wrong or the write procedure to do this

Comment: What are you storing inside `Session["AttachmentUrl"]`? Also there's no `Path.GetFileName` method that doesn't take any argument.

Comment: Session["AttachmentUrl"] has the url of the file to be Downloaded

Comment: But what's the value? Provide an example. How are you storing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(" + AttachmentName + "));
```

instead of

```
var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("'" + AttachmentName + "'"));
```

it shoud be replaced with (Server.MapPath(""+ AttachmentName + ""))

Answer (score 2):

That is because you have " ' " in your path.

> \BugTracker\ViewBug\'UploadedFiles\BugTrackerDataBase.xlsx''

Remove them an it should work. Like this

```
var fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(AttachmentName));
```